# Run All for VS 2015 runs all feature files simultaneously causing errors - C#/specflow/selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, specflow, xunit

I have a half dozen feature files with scenarios
I run the features one by one, all works fine
I click Run All on the Test Explorer
It opens windows for all scenarios simultaneously, skips the steps and then closes the windows, like its only processing my Before/After Scenario tags

(causing all my scenarios to fail)rather than working its way through the list of features alphabetically

Any ideas?

Comment: Which test runner are you using? NUnit, XUnit, MsTest, SpecFlow+ Runner?

Comment: i am using xunit as a runner

Answer (score 1):

It could be that XUnit is executing your tests in parallel.
Try to disable it and run the tests again.

Docu is here: https://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-parallel.html